# Game theory maths

Tags: algebra-precalculus, game-theory

I have a question that I can only partly solve. You bid for an company that you can increase the value by $80\%$

- A company is valued somewhere between $20M$ and $120M$ uniformly distributed. 
  Thus, $\text{exp(Value)} = 70M$
- Probability $60M$ bid succeed is $(60-20)/(120-20) = 0.40$
- What is the expected profit at time bid? Therefore, at the point of time when you make your bid of $60M$.

I have calculated $\text{exp(Value)}=(60/100) =0.60$;  $70M(0.60) = 42M$; $42M(1+80%) = 75.6M$. Is this correct? I presume the $60\%$ from the 60M bid divided by $100M$ range.

What should you bid if yo want to maximize you expected profit? This is an algebraic expression for expected profit as seen from the point in time when you are making your bid. Choose $X$ to maximize this expression. 
This needs to be an quadratic equation, but I'm not sure where to start.

Help appreciated.

Comment: You don't seem to be making use of the assumption "that you can increase the value by $80$%".  Is that because you don't use that assumption until some later part of the exercise?

Comment: The assumption is made after the successful bid of 60M. But I am not sure I have calculated it correctly by assuming the company worth at 42M after the successful bid , and than calculating the 80% added value.

Comment: I don't understand the set up.  Presumably the success or failure of the bid is related to the true value of the company, no?  Does the company know its true value, and so will sell to you at $60$ iff the true value is less than $60$? What "profit" are you referring to?

Comment: Don't use dollar signs when you type on this site.  The machine reads that as code.

Comment: I think (but am not sure) that you mean this:  Company XYZ knows its true value $V$, but all you know is that this value is uniformly chosen from $20$ to $120$.  You bid $60$ and the company sells it to you iff $V≤60$.  You then sell the company for $1.8\times V$.  What is your expected return on this investment?  Is this correct?

Comment: The question : You think the company in the current management is valued between 20M and 120M. ( you believe you can add 80% value ). If you bid 60M for the company , what is the probability that your bid succeeds? What is your expected profit if you do succeed in buy the company? Therefore, at the point in time when you make your bid of 60M, what is your expected profit. (warning: in calculating this expectation, don't forget the probability of your getting the company) Hope this helps

Comment: Doesn't help much.  Please check my version to see if you agree with that.  Your version is incomplete.  Is there another source of randomness involved in the success of the bid or is it just the valuation uncertainty?  Is there another source of randomness involved in the final sale?  In my version there is only the single source of randomness.

Comment: The warning part of the question has me calculating it as 60M(1-0.40)= 36M . Thus, 36(1+80%) = 64.8M

Comment: The valuation is of uncertainty.

Comment: Well, I think the problem as stated is too vague to answer.  I attempted to give an interpretation which could be answered, but of course my interpretation might not be what you intend.  You haven't said whether you agree or disagree with my reading, and I don't think there's anything else to be said until there is greater clarity.

Comment: I agree with you expected value increase of 1.8  x V after such bid. But I have seen an example similar to this question when as follows: Range 10 to 110. Successful bid of 50M has a 40% probability. The point in time of successful bid of 50M calculated the value of the company at 30M ( it didn't give the working on how this was derived of course) and than expected profit is: 30M(1.8) is 54M -50M =4M.

Comment: Well, under my interpretation a successful bid would tell you that $V$ was in fact uniformly distributed on $[20,60]$ , in your second example that would be $[10,50]$.  Thus the expected value of $V$, conditioned on the bid having succeeded would be $40$, or $30$ in your second example.  So I stand by my interpretation.

Comment: I should've had added in the example in the comments section. The added value was 75%. Thank you.

Comment: @Mark The wording of the exercise is fairly poor. Especially you have to highlight what is given and what you are asking for. Also the following part is not really obvious. :"You bid for an company that you can increase the value by 80%" What does that mean? Further explanation is needed in the question (**not comment**-section).

Answer (score 0):

As I read the question and comments, the following needs to be added

- The company is valued by its current owners somewhere between $20M$ and $120M$ uniformly distributed
- If you make a bid for it, the owners will sell if your bid exceeds their valuation
- If you buy the company, you will increase its value by $80\%$ and sell it at the new value

As you say, the chance your $60M$ bid is successful is $0.40$.  If the bid is successful the value is between $20M$ and $60M$ uniformly distributed.  After your increase, the value will be between $36M$ and $108M$ uniformly distributed.  The mean of this is $72M$.

Your expected profit is then $0.60 \cdot 0$ (if your bid fails) plus $0.40\cdot (72M-60M)=4.8M$

Comment: Referring back to the similar example in the comment section. The added value was 75%. Thus , 50M bid with 40% probability. 10(1.75) = 17.5M , 50(1.75) = 87.5M . Mean is 52.5. Therefore, (40%)(52.5-50) =1M which is the answer. This answer is correct. Still the last part has an quadratic term?

Comment: Do I have to find maximum point ?

Comment: @Mark:  as the question is given there is no requirement for a maximum point.  You could try to find the bid to replace $60M$ that maximizes the profit.  You would follow through the above analysis replacing $60M$ by $B$ including in the calculation of the probability the bid is successful.  You would get an answer involving $B$ that you could differentiate, set to $0\ldots$

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: If you make the $60M$ bid and it is rejected, you know the value now is more than $60M$.  You can come back with a higher bid and make a lot of money.  In fact, you should really hope the first bid is rejected.

Comment: Its been rejected and the owner is keeping all added value...of late.